# Microsoft Teams - As of today I cannot log in on one of my organization anymore

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am in two organizations, I use #2 much more than #1. Today I switched to #1 to work a little, when I tried to switch to #2, the program restarted, loaded #2, then it restarted again and loaded again #1. From now on, this is what always happen.

I am using teams on linux Mint 20.1. Logging out and in did not help, not rebooting several times,  I already tried purging the package (which did not delete any data because when I restarted I was still logged in, which is very bad, Microsoft), so I uninstalled teams, manually deleted everything in `~/.config/Microsoft` and  `~/.config/Microsoft Teams - Preview` and reinstalled it again. All the settings were gone and the authentication too of course, but the problem still persists.

Apparently, teams online works fine or firefox. Also on my android phone I am still logged in #2, but I dare not to log out because I cannot be locked from there too. I haven't tried teams on other desktops, but this is my main machine and I need to solve this problem.

Comment: What error do you receive when you attempt to log into the account you want to use?

Comment: Have you talked with your IT people about this?

Comment: @Ramhound no error, at least nothing is shown in the main UI